# how to search data based on various input fields

Tags: java, algorithm

I have set of data with 3 fields say **mobile_brand**, **price** and **rating**.
Now some one comes with **mobile_brand** and his budget(i.e his price range). I have to return the value which suits the customer price range brand with best rating. for example 
windows 200 100
windows 100 52 
android 300 9 
ios     200 99
windows 452 50
Now customer1 has following requirement mobile_type and his range
windows  500
which leaves him with 3 options but option1 has the best rating so, it should be returned. I am just scratching my head what data structure to use and how to compare. i tried using map but that is not the solution because there is no unique field to make a key
**NOTE:** There are more than 3 fields but for simplicity i have kept only 3 fields.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for a simple multi-class thing.

```
public class Computer{
    public String type;
    public int price;
    public int rating;
    public Computer(String type, int price, int rating){ this.type=type; this.price=price; this.rating=rating;
}
```

You can maybe do bang-for-buck by dividing rating by price. Obviously you can do some tinkering with this.

```
//elsewhere in a runner class
Computer mostEfficient=null;
double bestEfficiency=0;
for(int i=0;i<computers.length;i++){//where computers is an array of "Computer"s
    if(computers[i].type.Equals(typeWeAreLookingFor){
        double newEfficiency=(computers[i].rating+50)/((double)(computers[i].price));
        if(newEfficiency>bestEfficiency){
            mostEfficient=computers[i];
            bestEfficiency=newEfficiency;
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need to know how to read those fields from a text file or something